# Hadoop sort example fails with 'not a SequenceFile'. How set the SequenceFile

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to run **bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar sort input output**

but get an error "java.io.IOException: hdfs://master:9000/usr/ubuntu/input/file1 not a SequenceFile"

If I run **bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar wordcount input output** It's work.

So I can't figure out how to deal with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message here is exactly right; the `sort` example is expecting a [sequence file](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SequenceFile) - a flat file of binary keys and values as input, the kind that are often generated as output from MapReduce jobs.

However, the `wordcount` example is not expecting a sequence file in particular as input, merely a text file which is read in with the keys being the offset (line number) into the file, with the value being the line content.

Seeing as the input files you have are not sequence files per se, `sort` cannot run using them.

Comment: Well with your current input files, you cant make it work I'm afraid. However, why exactly do you want it to sort them? The `wordcount` example will guarantee sorting within each output file at least, so there is no reason to sort your input files for it. Bear in mind that the examples in the `hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar` are just that - examples - you won't be using them in practice.

Answer (score 0):

@Jork, If you observe sort the example given in hadoop-examples-1.0.4.jar, You can change the Input and Output Formats through command line arguements, Or You can change in the program from SequenceFileInputFormat to Text type. [hadoop](/questions/tagged/hadoop)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Here , https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Sort, it says "The inputs and outputs must be Sequence files."
You should convert your input file to a hadoop sequence file, I wish there was an easier way. I found this tutorial helpful, good luck! https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/apache-hadoop/hadoop-sequence-file-example/